# How to get zoomed preview(bitmap) in textureview?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, textureview

I want to get zoomed preview in the format of bitmap from textureview. when I tried to get it returned me full bitmap without zoomed translation. I managed to get zoomed preview using following code>  `mTempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mTempBitmap, 0,0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);` it returns me zoomed bitmap positioning at very left-top corner (maybe its because I'm passing 0,0 coordinates in above function. So I tried to search how to get actual co-ordinates of zoomed image (bitmap) but no luck. so please help me to get the zoomed image preview (bitmap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem & its working for me.
just go through the link below where I have posted the answer

https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera/issues/367